# JAVA : Transferring files through socket

Tags: java, stream, streaming, filestream

**What I'm doing :**
I am writing a program on client-server file transfer through socket connection.
The server sends files to client computer through buffered `ObjectOutputStream`.
The file is being sent by sending it *byte by byte*

**What I want to do :**
To be able to send pause/cancel signal from both end.

**The problem :**
As the file is being sent *byte by byte*, I'm confused how to send a pause/cancel
signal from server to client. Help please.

***Additional Info :***
If I send an integer/a byte from the server to the client to indicate that the 
transfer should be paused or cancelled, it should be confusing the client computer
may read these bytes as part of the file!

Comment: Add relevant code what you have tried?

Comment: @THANGA This is part of my problem, the main code will be confusing here. Could you suggest me anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't use an ObjectOutptuStream as this can be inefficient. Sending one Byte at a time is very inefficient.

I would use a DataOutputStream instead.

In any case the solution is much the same.  The sender can pause by not sending data. The receiver can pause by not reading data which will cause the sender to block.

Comment: It's initialized like this
`ObjectOutputStream os=new ObjectOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(...))`
Is it still inefficient?

Comment: ObjectOuptutStream is already buffered. To send one Byte takes over 70 bytes, each additional Byte takes about 10 bytes. If you use DataOutputStream you can blocks of `byte[]` in a single call which will be at least 100x faster and 10x smaller.

Comment: Is there any `OutputStream` where I just write bytes and it _automatically_ writes it to a buffer, and whenever the buffer is full it'd send the buffered bytes?

Comment: AFAIK, Every OutputStream in the JDK does this except BufferedOutputStream and ObjectOutputStream. ;) I use DataOutputStream for methods like writeUTF() to send Strings like the name and wrietInt() or writeLong() to send the length.

Comment: I still don't get it, if I use 'DataOutputStream' and write the bytes(not as byte[] arrays, by sending one byte after another), will it still be bufferd efficiently?
And another thing, how do I send a signal to the client that the transfer is to be cancelled? (it was stupid asking how to pause the transfer)

Comment: If you use byte[] you don't need buffering. If you write one byte at a time you need buffering which which then add these to a byte[] for you. Normally you have a byte[] already because its also the most efficient way to read a file.

Comment: If i'm not mistaken it means I should use data streams, write _indivdual bytes(not `byte[]`)_ to outputstream and read the data as `byte[]` form inputstream.
And can you please give me some idea about sending *STOP TRANSFER* signal from server to client?

Comment: You haven't explained why you want to send one byte at a time. Normally this is done because you have *absolutely no choice*, but since you are uploading/downloading a file, it doesn't make any sense.  Like I said already, you can pause from either end by not reading or writing.